# how to configure postifx to share inbox into 2 domains?

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I am trying to configure postfix to use 2 domains for my accounts, for example, I had **example.com** and now I want to use **example.net** , my current mail use my Unix Accounts ... I add user usermail and I get **usermail@example.com** , so now, I want all those accounts and the new accounts to receive and send all mails from **usermail@example.net** too...

So, what after set the domain, MX records and all... I added in my linux (debian) as host (in /var/hosts) the ip xx.xx.xx.xx example.net (example.com was already there) and in my postfix configuration I thought about to treat it as an alias domain... so, I did this:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
virtual_alias_domains = example.net
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

/etc/postfix/virtual:
postmaster@example.com postmaster (my Unix Account)
```

Then I did postmap **/etc/postfix/virtual** and **/etc/init.d/postfix restart**

I can send mails to my old accounts in @example.net .. but I cant receive them.. it doesnt work.. and of course I can't send mails from those accounts.

Any idea how to make this configuration? or if my configuration has something wrong??

I added my domain as another VirtualHost on my apache.. not as an alias of the other
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check `/etc/aliases` (or `/etc/postfix/aliases`, check `main.cf` to see exact location) if there is any alias for postmaster user. Delete it if so because mail will be delivered to expended address.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/local

> Mail for name is delivered to the alias name, to destinations in
>   ~name/.forward, to the mailbox owned by the user name, or it is sent
>   back as undeliverable.